# How do I setup my db before unicorn starts and does it 4 times? (because I have 4 workers)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper, unicorn

I'm developing a modular Sinatra app. I use unicorn. The App needs some initial setup for db etc, where do I do that?

my config.ru:

```
require './main.rb'

disable :run #disable internal webserver

run App.new
```

my Procfile:

```
web: unicorn -p 8080 -c ./unicorn.rb
```

my unicorn.rb:

```
worker_processes 4
timeout 30
```

The setup happens somewhere in main.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, outside of your application, as something that runs before unicorn is started.

You can potentially place the setup portion of `main.rb` at the top of `unicorn.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

## ActiveRecord

If you use [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) as your ORM of choice, you can add something like this to your Unicorn [before_fork](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-before_fork) hook. This will close any existing connections to your database.

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end
```

And also add this to [after_fork](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-after_fork) hook. This will establish new connection after each unicorn fork.

```
after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

## DataMapper

And if you use [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/), you can add something like this to your [before_fork](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-before_fork) hook. This time you will use [DataObjects](https://github.com/datamapper/do) to dispose connections - [DataObjects](https://github.com/datamapper/do) is a gem that rewrites existing Ruby database drivers with more standard interface. [DataObjects](https://github.com/datamapper/do) are used internally by [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) to manage connection to database. After disposing connections [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) will reconnect when needed.

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  DataObjects::Pooling.pools.each do |pool|
    pool.dispose
  end
end
```